# set htaccess condition if servername is www-static.example.com

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, yslow

I have want cookie-free subdomain, to improve yslow,

Can i in htaccess check witch hostname is use

In my case if www-static.example.com is called, then i want to set

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ServerSignature Off
Options -Indexes
FileETag none

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Cookie
    Header unset Set-Cookie
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|gif)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 years"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2 years"
    ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 2 years"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2 years"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2 years"
    ExpiresByType image/jpe "access plus 2 years"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2 years"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2 years"
</IfModule>
```

But when i visit www.example.com i don't want this to be set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Apache 2.4+ you can try putting the whole block of directives in an `<If>` block using an Apache Expression that tests the requested hostname.

For example:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www-static.example.com'">

# :
# Directives go here...
# :

</If>
```

---

A few notes on your existing directives:

> ```
> <IfModule mod_headers.c>
>     Header unset ETag
>     Header unset Cookie
>     Header unset Set-Cookie
> </IfModule>
> ```

There wouldn't seem to be any need to wrap all your blocks in `<IfModule>` wrappers.

`Cookie` is a *request* header, so you would need to use the `RequestHeader` directive instead, not `Header` (which applies to *response* headers). However, cookies should not have been set on this domain to begin with, so this should be unnecessary (and defeats the point of having a cookie-less domain in the first place). Likewise, unsetting the `Set-Cookie` should be unnecessary, since it shouldn't have been set in the first place.

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
> </IfModule>
> ```

Unless your intention is to override mod_rewrite directives in a parent config then this would seem unnecessary?

> ```
> <IfModule mod_expires.c>
>     ExpiresActive on
> </IfModule>
>
> <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|gif)$">
>     ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 years"
> </FilesMatch>
>
> <IfModule mod_expires.c>
>     ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2 years"
>     ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 2 years"
>     ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2 years"
>     ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2 years"
>     ExpiresByType image/jpe "access plus 2 years"
>     ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2 years"
>     ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2 years"
> </IfModule>
> ```

You have mod_expires directives both inside and outside of `<IfModule>` containers - which doesn't really make sense. Plus you have an `ExpiresDefault` directive for file extensions which are already covered by the more specific `ExpiresByType` directives. `ExpiresDefault` should be used as a default for any other *static resources* that are served from this host.

Incidentally, the correct mime-type for jpg/jpeg/jpe files is `image/jpeg`. So, the other two related mime-types (`image/jpg` and `image/jpe`) are redundant - your server will only return one of these anyway, so you can double check by looking at the HTTP response your server is sending back.

So, your mod_expires directives should be written something like:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2 years"
    ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 2 years"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2 years"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2 years"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2 years"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 years"
</IfModule>
```

Mind you, if all static resources are going to be "access plus 2 years", then you only strictly need the `ExpiresDefault` directive.